# UIAlertView with textfield: how to dismiss if RETURN is pressed and how to hide keyboard if dismissed?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, xamarin.ios

I have customized UIAlertView a bit. My implementation inherits from UIAlertView and adds a textfield to it. If the textfield is tapped, the iPad's keyboard shows up.
Would I would like to achieve in additon however:

- If the user presses "OKAY" in the alert view, the keyboard does not go away. How can I realize that?
- The on the keyboard "RETURN" is pressed, I would like to dismiss the alert view (and of course hide the keyboard). Also here: how the heck..?

The code of my custom alert view can be seen here: http://www.wildsau.net/post/2011/01/28/iOS-UIAlertView-with-a-UITextField-a-MonoTouch-implementation.aspx

Note that it is MonoTouch but any solution working for ObjC, I will be able to translate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To dismiss the keyboard when the user taps the alert's OK button, in the appropriate alert delegate method

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
```

do this:

```
[myTextField resignFirstResponder]
```

To dismiss your alert view programmatically, use this:

```
- (void)dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex animated:(BOOL)animated
```

Then you use the same code in clickedButtonAtIndex: to resignFirstResponder to cancel the keyboard.

Comment: Okay, thanks. One last piece of the puzzle is missing: how can I capture the keyboard's "RETURN" key to call the dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:?

Comment: use the UITextField delegate method `- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField`

Comment: Hm, first part works. Clicking OKAY dismisses the keyboard. But hitting return will only remove the cursor from the textfield, dismiss the alert but leave the keyboard visible. What could cause that behavior?